# Client Server version sync in single page applications

Tags: javascript, single-page-application

I am looking for the ideas to sync version of client javascript and server APIs in a single page applications.

I have come up with following ideas -

1. Push update notification from server and ask user to refresh
2. Keep a version info in each API call and ask client to refresh as soon as there is version mismatch
3. keep supporting the old server version as long as all clients are updated(by closing their existing sessions and opening a new tab/window)

How is it generally done? Would like to discuss more ideas here and pros and cons of the options given above.